# WooCommerce star ratings shows strange symbols

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have very strange problem with woocommerce product ratings. Just go and check this product:

http://produkti.revita.bg/shop/arnold-iron-pack-20-dozi/

and see the last tab which is for the reviews. Instead of showing stars for rating it shows some strange things. I have gone through the CSS and check some php files, but I'm really stuck at this.

I think it's a CSS problem because actually the ratings are there but the stars are not showing.

```
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-1 {width: 2em}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-1:after {content: "e021"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1.active:after,.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1:hover:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-1.active:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-1:hover:after {content: "e020"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-2,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-2 {width: 3em}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-2:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-2:after {content: "e021e021"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-2.active:after,.woocommerce p.stars a.star-2:hover:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-2.active:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-2:hover:after {content: "e020e020"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-3,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-3 {width: 4em}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-3:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-3:after {content: "e021e021e021"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-3.active:after,.woocommerce p.stars a.star-3:hover:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-3.active:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-3:hover:after {content: "e020e020e020"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-4,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-4 {width: 5em}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-4:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-4:after {content: "e021e021e021e021"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-4.active:after,.woocommerce p.stars a.star-4:hover:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-4.active:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-4:hover:after {content: "e020e020e020e020"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-5,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-5 {width: 6em;border:0}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-5:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-5:after {content: "e021e021e021e021e021"}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-5.active:after,.woocommerce p.stars a.star-5:hover:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-5.active:after,.woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-5:hover:after {content: "e020e020e020e020e020"}
```

This is the code I found in woocommerce.css for this stars rating. I have downloaded again the woocommerce plugin and compared this css block with the original one but they seem identical. The comments are allowed on the products because I have read that this might cause problems. I have also checked the woocommerce setting and from there the needed checkboxes for the ratings are checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `content` isn't escaped. The `e021` instances should all be preceded by backslashes, so they become valid CSS hex values. For example, for three stars:

```
content: "\e021\e021\e021";
```

Comment: I have added the backslashes  in front of everyone as per your example but it shows again the same things

Comment: That's impossible. You need to clear your cache. It looks fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1:after, .woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-1:after { content: "e021"; }
```

change it to:

```
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1:after, .woocommerce-page p.stars a.star-1:after { content: "\e021"; }
```

Comment: PERFECT! thank you very much when I added the last one now it seems everything works great. Thank you very much :)

Comment: How is this any different than my answer?

Comment: Ah sorry I though this answer is again from you the big thank you was for you :)